# INDEX(GoogleFinance("USDIDR", "PRICE", F530),2,2) F530 = cell with date

Tags: google-sheets

`INDEX(GoogleFinance("USDIDR", "PRICE", F530),2,2) F530 = cell with date` (formatted to date),
please help, how to apply above formula for stock listed in Indian markets ( NSE or BSE)?

Answer (score 0):

You can select a stock market by adding the market's code in front of the stock code, e.g. `NSE:PNB` will look up PNB on NSE.

So in Google Sheets the lookup would be something like:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE("NSE:PNB","PRICE")`